# Why does the priest in my party level slower than me?

Tags: tera

I have a warrior and my girlfriend is playing as a priest.  When we are questing together, she levels slower.

By the time I got to level 11, she was a full level behind.

Comment: have you both completed the same amount of quests?

Comment: @JLaBella we only play together, and we follow the same quests, so yes. The only experience differences I can think of is in killing mobs, but from the docs I've read, our experience should be shared evenly?

Comment: Was she always in the neighborhood while you where smashing things?

Comment: @MennoGouw define "in the neighborhood"?

Comment: you might have killed things while she wasn't in the area to receive the shared exp.

Comment: @JLaBella How close does she need to bee?

Comment: Im not sure as I have not played Tera in quite some time (which is why I'm not saying this is the answer). All I remember is it is pretty close.

Comment: Maybe she forgot a quest.